# Char* to QByteArray

Tags: массивы, qt, указатели, char

Доброго времени суток. Существует некоторая многоступенчатая программа, в которой вперемешку используются модули QT и C++. В функции самого глубокого уровня формируется некий массив source_array[6]. Он возвращается в функцию уровнем выше, в виде указателя.

```
char* catched_array= handler(in_array);
QByteArray array_to_send;
```

я вижу что передается все правильно, catched array содержит те данные, которые мне нужны. Теперь мне нужно преобразовать его в QByteArray, и здесь появилась проблема. Append, простой конструктор, fromRawData либо зануляют преобразуемый массив, либо в нужный мне QByteArray записывается мусор. Пробовал сделать insert, но тогда меняются значения в catched_array на какие-то левые. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а вот так пробовали `QByteArray a(catched_array, 6);`

Comment: @KoVadim пробовал, catched_array весь зануляется. Такое впечатление, что указатель прыгает куда-то в незаполненную область памяти или теряется...

Comment: а что внутри handler ? malloc или просто указатель на локальный массив внутри функции?

Comment: Вы оказались правы, нужно было делать malloc. Был просто указатель на локальный массив внутри функции, в этом и было дело.

Comment: тогда не забывайте и память освобождать.